# Comparing two array of objects in JavaScript and update the values by comparing Keys

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1 = [{"id": "15-1", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}}, 
           {"id": "15-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "15-3", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}},
           {"id": "15-4", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "16-2", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}} ]

var arr2 =[{"id": "16-1", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "16-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}} ]
```

Merge both the arrays and The id's which are similar should update their values as per the arr2
Here, we would like to get the final array as

```
finalArray = [{"id": "15-1", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}}, 
                  {"id": "15-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
                  {"id": "15-3", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}},
                  {"id": "15-4", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
                  {"id": "16-1", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}},
                  {"id": "16-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}} ]
```

Comment: What have you tried to do this? Did you google?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to achieve the desired results:

```js
var arr1 = [{"id": "15-1", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}}, 
           {"id": "15-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "15-3", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}},
           {"id": "15-4", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "16-2", "value": {"x": {"on": false}}} ]

var arr2 =[{"id": "16-1", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}}, 
           {"id": "16-2", "value": {"x": {"on": true}}} ]

const mergedArray = [...arr1, ...arr2];
const uniqueData = [...mergedArray.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj.id, obj), new Map()).values()];
console.log(uniqueData);
```

Comment: can you explain the code?

Comment: I think it is self-explanatory. What part do you want an explanation for?

Comment: reduce method second parameter

Comment: That refers to the `currentValue` of the `reduce` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr1 = [
  { id: "15-1", value: { x: { on: false } } },
  { id: "15-2", value: { x: { on: true } } },
  { id: "15-3", value: { x: { on: false } } },
  { id: "15-4", value: { x: { on: true } } },
  { id: "16-2", value: { x: { on: false } } },
];

var arr2 = [
  { id: "16-1", value: { x: { on: true } } },
  { id: "16-2", value: { x: { on: true } } },
];
function merge(a, b, prop) {
  var reduced = a.filter(aitem => !b.find(bitem => aitem[prop] === bitem[prop]))
  return reduced.concat(b);
}

console.log(merge(arr1,arr2,"id"));
```